# What is the established story/lore of Infernals and their realm in the IKRPG?

Tags: story, iron-kingdoms

I'm contemplating running a campaign with the new IKRPG that may or may not end up (way down the line) confronting some Infernal creatures, possibly even on their home turf. What information is available about Infernals and where they reside?

I'm interested in any answers that can relate more directly to the new IKRPG release, or even the WarMachine/Hordes miniature war games. Information from the original IK d20 game could potentially be helpful, particularly if more recent information is lacking (which I strongly suspect to be the case based on other research). Any information about Infernals is valuable, but extensive answers with detailed sources would be awesome.

Comment: AFAIK, the old Iron Kingdoms and the new Iron Kingdoms are just system changes/updates/returning-to-in-print (the d20 IK core book went OOP ages ago), while the setting it shares with Warmachine has never changed/rebooted. Is that impression incorrect?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I was thinking that too for a while, but there is some refinement in the general lore. And then there's psuedo-teleports like `Mirage` (not to mention a ton of teleport-like effects happening in WarmaHordes), so I can't help but wonder if there are some differences between old and new Iron Kingdoms. But if the best answer is the d20 material (which I don't have direct access to), I'm more than happy to mark it.

Comment: I am new to IK and currently reading the core book. When I read about the Infernals I had a strange feeling why they mentionend them at all. I can not make any use of it in the games besides telling stories about mighty and evil creatures. I suspect that they are part of IK and thus needed to be mentioned, but the authors did not have space or time to write more. Maybe they thought this should be part of another publication for more experienced players or due to marketing reasons (sell more books).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Core Rules of the revised IKRPG, infernals are mentioned twice (pages 35 and 96) and infernalism is mentioned once (page 85). The information on infernals/infernalism combined takes up less than a page and pretty much leaves almost everything up to the imagination.

In fact, most of the information on infernals actually focuses on the possible connections to the Thamarite faith rather than the infernals themselves. There's no mention of what domains infernals typically control (such as teleportation effects as in the original RPG), and only a vague connection of infernals, Thamar, The Vanished (6 out of 8 Iosan deities are missing), and human magic.

The only real concrete information we're given is that infernals are "mysterious but vastly powerful entities that dwell beyond Caen and Urcaen" who gather mortal souls for unknown purposes. They are said to be highly skilled in arcane arts, to the extent that it is believed the Orgoth's dark gods may have been exceptionally powerful infernals.

I'm not too sure how this differs to the older content on infernals, other than restrictions on most teleportation unless bargained for with an Infernal of the appropriate (but unknown) stature. In addition, I don't know how to resolve differences between the content of the new RPG and the old one. So, I feel that this answer is still incomplete.

Comment: Due to lack of appearance of better answers, I'm awarding you the bounty.

Comment: @waxeagle: I'm disappointed that this seems to be the only answer. Thanks for trying, though.